# High on %wa from top command, is there any way to constrain it?

Tags: linux, centos, io, cgroup

Here's my last top info before it stucks:

```
top - 18:26:10 up 238 days,  5:43,  3 users,  load average: 1782.01, 1824.47, 1680.36
Tasks: 1938 total,   1 running, 1937 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.4%us,  3.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 94.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65923016k total, 65698400k used,   224616k free,    13828k buffers
Swap: 33030136k total, 17799704k used, 15230432k free,   157316k cached
```

As you can see, since I've launched about 2000 processes executing `hadoop get` command, **%wa** is very high. I limit memory and cpu in `cgroups`, will it be helpful if I limit disk IO, too? If so, could anyone give me some idea on how to do that in `cgroups`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have high IOWAIT you need to verify what kind of disk you are using for doing what you are doing, for example, If I have an usb drive and I would like to write a document, I don't is good idea execute 3000 process in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have enough RAM to run these 2000 processes.

We can see here that you have used *all* of your 64GB of RAM, and are also using an additional 17GB of swap. Your server is [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), trying to swap data in and out, valiantly *trying* to let each of those 2000 processes do something.

But of course it's not working.

There are only two solutions here:

1. Start fewer processes, so that you do not run out of RAM. (Try 1500.)
2. Add more RAM to the server, so that it can run all of the processes.

Comment: So, if I limit the maximum number of processes that a specific user can fork to, say, 100, will it help?

Comment: @JasonZhu That depends on how many simultaneous users you have. It will probably not hurt much. :)